# Can't save the file as an ipynb file from jupyterlab

Tags: github, download, jupyter-lab

I need to download an ipynb file from jupyter-lab on my Mac. For some reason there is no download option in file part. Is there any other way to save my Jupyter file on my desktop to be able to load the file to my Github?
thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

To download a file from JupyterLab use the file browser:

- open context menu on the file of choice, and
- select "Download":

[image: context menu display]

This is also documented in the official documentation [Working with Files](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/files.html) chapter, which even includes this video deomnstartion: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wl7Ozl6rMcc